# sr*() method not dissecting the answered packets in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I extended Scapy to support a new protocol for my testing. I see that the `sniff()` command is able to dissect the packets automatically after I stitched 2 layers together using `bind_layers()`. I was expecting that should be good enough for dissections. Whenever I use `sniff()` I see dissections are working.

But when I use the `sr()` or `sr1()` functions I see that the answered packet is not dissected and Scapy reports it as `Raw`. I also see that it has some extra packets as part of answered.

More details about the protocol being added:

The protocol that I added is a PCEP protocol which is tcp based and runs on port 4189. I create a python socket and convert it into scapy supersocket using StreamSocket(). We send these PCEP messages on top of the scapy's supersocket.

The Packet will be layered like this: IP()/TCP()/PCEP()

```
connection, pcc_address = pce.accept() <---- This accepts a TCP connection from the client
pcc_client=StreamSocket(connection) <---- Here I convert the python socket into scapy super socket.
```

Example packet :

If I want to send a keepalive this is how I craft the message. pcc_client object is to send the packet.

```
>>>>>> pkt.show2()
###[ PCEP common header ]###
  Version= 1L
  Flags= 0L
  Type= PCEPKeepaliveMsg
  Length= 4
>>>  pcc_client.send(pkt) 
>>> pcc_client
<scapy.supersocket.StreamSocket object at 0x115b890>
```

Issue:

The same way I create a message called PCInitiate and I am sending using

```
>>>pcc_client.sr1(pccinit)
```

Below `a[0][0]` is the packet that I sent and the received packet is stored as `Raw`. I was expecting it to be dissected. For some reason I see its not getting dissected. I also notice a bunch of strings `' \x02\x00\x04'` appended to the response from UUT. I can recognize these strings which are Keepalive messages. These are not responses to the packet I sent but somehow it shows up in this output. How do I make `sr()` function dissect the response from the UUT. I see `hashret()` and `answers()` methods used in `sndrcv()`. What is the use of those methods. Can someone help me with my query?

```
>>> a[0][0]
<PCEPCommonHeader  Type=PCInitiate |<PCInitiate  srp_object=<SRP_Object  srpIdNumber=0x10     path_setup_type=<path_setup_type_tlv  |> |> lsp_object=<LSP_Object  plspid=0x0 symbolic_path_name=    <symbolic_path_name_tlv  tlvValue='SERVICE-1418979625354-9F1166-10.126.147.23-10.126.147.1' |> |>     end_points_object=<End_Points_Object  SourceIPv4Address=10.0.0.1 DestinationIPv4Address=10.0.0.6 |>     ero_object=<ERO_Object  sr_eros=[<SR_ERO_SubObject  Fflag=F Mflag=M SID=2260992 |>, <SR_ERO_SubObject      Fflag=F Mflag=M SID=2674688 |>, <SR_ERO_SubObject  Fflag=F Mflag=M SID=3096576 |>] |> |>>
>>> a[0][1]
<Raw  load=' \n\x00x!\x10\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x1b\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01 \x10\x00DT\x00`\x91\x00\x11\x007SERVICE-1418979625354-9F1166-10.126.147.23-10.126.147.1\x00\x07\x10\x00\x1c\x05\x08\x10\t\x00"\x80\x00\x05\x08\x10\t\x00(\xd0\x00\x05\x08\x10\t\x00/@\x00 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04 \x02\x00\x04' |>
```

Comment: You do not give enough information about the command you entered (e.g. `sr()` call parameters) and the protocol you have created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must tell `StreamSocket` the type of packets it will receive (`Raw` is the default). You can do that by using `basecls=` optional argument:

```
connection, pcc_address = pce.accept()
pcc_client = StreamSocket(connection, basecls=PCEPCommonHeader)
```

You will then need to implement `hashret()` and `answers`. Their docstrings from `Packet` explains it well:

- `hashret()` is a kind of hash function that "returns a string that has the same value for a request and its answer".
- `answers()` is "true if self is an answer to other".

`hashret()` is not mandatory, but if properly implemented it will improve the performances.

Comment: thanks for your response. Is this needed only for the sr() related functions? Also When I add the basecls as part of the StreamSocket as per your advise I see that now the the sr() function is not returning its just stuck for an answer i guess..                           Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
..

Comment: It looks like we need to overload answers()/hashret() for scapy to detect an answer for the sent packet. I am not sure what to add in these functions. Can you please help me understand the use of these 2 functions?

Comment: I see that the parsing now works and sr() is not stuck waiting for a reply. I do face a small issue where I see that the receive buffer gets accumulated  and that causes parsing issues. Say I use pkt=pcc_client.recv() I see that pkt has 2 or 3 messages. Instead I want to be able to parse it as soon as I receive a single message. Should I reduce my buffer size? I see sniff() works perfectly and they use recv(MTU). Please advise.

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. You should ask another question and explain it with a bit of code.