# scapy: Unable to pass dict with sub keys to ByteEnum Field

Tags: python, scapy

I have created a dictionary like this for ByteEnum field in scapy. When I am passing this _PCEP_ERR_values dict to the ByteEnum field its erroring out. with a traceback saying unhashable type dict. How do I pass a dictionary with sub keys to ByteEnumField?

This is the snip of how I have created the Layer:

```
_PCEP_ERR_types = {1: "PCEP session establishment failure",
                   3: "Unknown Object"}

_PCEP_ERR_values = {_PCEP_ERR_types[1]: {1: "Reception of an invalid Open message or a non Open message",
                                     2: "No Open message received before the expiration of the OpenWait timer",
                                     3: "Unacceptable and non-negotiable session characteristics",
                                     4: "Unacceptable but negotiable session characteristics",
                                     5: "Reception of a second Open message with still unacceptable session characteristics",
                                     6: "Reception of a PCErr message proposing unacceptable session characteristics",
                                     7: "No Keepalive or PCErr message received before the expiration of the KeepWait timer"},
                    _PCEP_ERR_types[3]: {1: "Unrecognized object class",
                                         2: "Unrecognized object Type"}}

class PCEPErrorObject(Packet):

  '''PCEP-ERROR Object to notify error conditions in a PCEP session'''

  name = 'PCEP-ERROR OBJECT'

  common_object = PCEPCommonObjectHeader(oclass=13,oType=1)
  fields_desc =     [PacketField("common_object_header",common_object,PCEPCommonObjectHeader),
                      ByteField("Reserved",0),
                      ByteField("flags",0),
                      ByteEnumField("ET", 0, _PCEP_ERR_types),
                      ByteEnumField("EV", 0, _PCEP_ERR_values)]
```

Snip of the trace back when I execute the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pcep-v3.py", line 1624, in <module>
    class PCEPErrorObject(Packet):
  File "./pcep-v3.py", line 1635, in PCEPErrorObject
    ByteEnumField("EV", 0, _PCEP_ERR_values)]
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 771,
in __init__
    EnumField.__init__(self, name, default, enum, "B")
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 718,
in __init__
    s2i[enum[k]] = k
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not doing what you think it does. `_PCEP_ERR_values` is supposed to associate a numerical value to a string value (just like `_PCEP_ERR_types`), and you associate a text value to a dictionary.

You must use a `MultiEnumField` and you have an excellent example of use of that type of fields in the `ICMP` layer in [Scapy source code](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/tip/scapy/layers/inet.py?at=default#cl-590).

```
_PCEP_ERR_types = {1: "PCEP session establishment failure",
                   3: "Unknown Object"}

_PCEP_ERR_values = {
    1: {1: "Reception of an invalid Open message or a non Open message",
        2: "No Open message received before the expiration of the OpenWait timer",
        3: "Unacceptable and non-negotiable session characteristics",
        4: "Unacceptable but negotiable session characteristics",
        5: "Reception of a second Open message with still unacceptable session characteristics",
        6: "Reception of a PCErr message proposing unacceptable session characteristics",
        7: "No Keepalive or PCErr message received before the expiration of the KeepWait timer"},
    3: {1: "Unrecognized object class",
        2: "Unrecognized object Type"}
}


class PCEPErrorObject(Packet):
    '''PCEP-ERROR Object to notify error conditions in a PCEP session'''
    name = 'PCEP-ERROR OBJECT'
    common_object = PCEPCommonObjectHeader(oclass=13,oType=1)
    fields_desc =     [PacketField("common_object_header",common_object,PCEPCommonObjectHeader),
                       ByteField("Reserved",0),
                       ByteField("flags",0),
                       ByteEnumField("ET", 0, _PCEP_ERR_types),
                       MultiEnumField("EV", 0, _PCEP_ERR_values,
                                      depends_on=lambda pkt: pkt.ET,
                                      fmt="B")]
```

By the way (totally unrelated) you should have a look to the `dispatch_hook` `Packet` to replace your `common_object_header`; this might save you an unwanted indirection to access common fields value (you could use `pkt.field_name` instead of `pkt.common_object_header.field_name`)

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the `MultiEnumField` and thought this should be implemented with something like `ConditionalField`. Is there any good documentation on the various field types or is inspecting the source code the best way to get acquainted with them?

Comment: I'd say the file `fields.py` in Scapy source code is your best chance (https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/tip/scapy/fields.py) ;-). For that one, what the OP wanted to do made me think of the ICMP protocol so I just had a look there because I had forgotten how it was implemented. Anyway `ConditionalField` would have been OK here but more complicated.

Comment: Great!! it works. thats exactly what i was looking for!! I will also try to implement the dispatch_hook as per your suggestion..

Comment: Glad it worked! Did you finally manage to do something with your previous question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958567/)

Comment: Not yet!! I am rewriting my dissectors again as it was not able to parse some of the messages properly!! working on the dispatch_hook that you suggested.. and then will work on the sr()..will update that post as soon as I see the results :)

Comment: I just posted another question related to dispatch_hook(). Not sure how to bind or link the layers if i use them. Please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018040/scapy-using-dispatch-hook