# Using dispatch_hook()

Tags: python, scapy

How do I link different layers using dispatch_hook(). I have the packet like this. I just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this using dispatch_hook().

This is how I craft my packet:

```
>>>> pkt=PCEPCommonHeader(Type=6)/PCEPErrorMsg(error_objects=[PCEPErrorObject()])

>>> pkt.show()
###[ PCEP common header ]###
  Version= 1
  Flags= 0
  Type= PCEPErrorMsg
  Length= None
###[ PCEPErrorMsg ]###
     \error_objects\
      |###[ PCEP-ERROR OBJECT ]###
      |  \common_object_header\
      |   |###[ PCEP Common Object Header ]###
      |   |  oclass= PCEP-ERROR
      |   |  oType= 1
      |   |  resflags=
      |   |  pflag=
      |   |  iflag=
      |   |  obLength= 4
      |  Reserved= 0
      |  flags= 0
      |  ET= 0
      |  EV= 0
>>>
```

Code Snip:

```
connection, pcc_address = pce.accept()
pcc_client=StreamSocket(connection,basecls=PCEPCommonHeader)

_PCEP_types      = {6:"PCEPErrorMsg"}
_object_class    = {13: "PCEP-ERROR"}
_PCEP_ERR_types  = {3: "Unknown Object"}
_PCEP_ERR_values = {3: {1: "Unrecognized object class",
                        2: "Unrecognized object Type"}}
class PCEPCommonHeader(Packet):
  """This is the common header for all PCEP packets"""
  name = "PCEP common header"
  #Common Header Length is 4 bytes
  fields_desc = [BitField("Version",1,3),
                   BitField("Flags",0,5),
                   ByteEnumField("Type", 2, _PCEP_types),
                   ShortField("Length", None)]

class PCEPCommonObjectHeader(Packet):
    """Common Header for the PCEP Objects"""
    #Common ObjectHeader Length is 4 Bytes
    name = "PCEP Common Object Header"


    fields_desc = [ByteEnumField("oclass",0, _object_class),
                       BitField("oType",0,4),
                       FlagsField("resflags", 0x0, 2, "Res"),
                       FlagsField("pflag", 0x0, 1, "P"),
                       FlagsField("iflag", 0x0, 1, "I"),
                       ShortField("obLength", 4)]

class PCEPErrorObject(Packet):

  '''PCEP-ERROR Object to notify error conditions in a PCEP session'''

  name = 'PCEP-ERROR OBJECT'

  common_object = PCEPCommonObjectHeader(oclass=13,oType=1)
  fields_desc = [PacketField("common_object_header",common_object,PCEPCommonObjectHeader),
                  ByteField("Reserved",0),
                  ByteField("flags",0),
                  ByteEnumField("ET", 0, _PCEP_ERR_types),
                  MultiEnumField("EV", 0, _PCEP_ERR_values,depends_on=lambda pkt: pkt.ET,fmt="B")]

class PCEPErrorMsg(Packet):

  fields_desc = [PacketListField("error_objects",None,PCEPErrorObject)]


bind_layers( PCEPCommonHeader, PCEPErrorMsg, Type=6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind `.dispatch_hook()` is to have a main class, let's call it `Protocol` that inherits (directly or not) from `Packet`, and to have derived classes (that inherit, directly or not, from `Protocol` or from `Packet`); let's say we have `Protocol1` and `Protocol2`.

The `.dispatch_hook()` method will be called when you (or Scapy) instantiate the class by calling `Protocol()`. It is called with the exact same arguments that you passed to `Protocol()`, and returns the class that is going to be (really) used.

Let's take a real example, from Scapy code. `Ether()` (Ethernet v2) and `Dot3()` () are layer two protocols that are very similar: both start with the six bytes destination address, followed by the six bytes source address. `Ether()` next two bytes are the type of the payload, whereas `Dot3()` next two bytes are the packet size. Since a packet cannot be longer than 1500 bytes, and that the Ethernet types cannot be less than 1500 (1536 is the minimum to be precise).

From Scapy code (file `scapy/layers/l2.py`):

```
class Ether(Packet):
    [...]
    @classmethod
    def dispatch_hook(cls, _pkt=None, *args, **kargs):
        if _pkt and len(_pkt) >= 14:
            if struct.unpack("!H", _pkt[12:14])[0] <= 1500:
                return Dot3
        return cls

class Dot3(Packet):
    [...]
    @classmethod
    def dispatch_hook(cls, _pkt=None, *args, **kargs):
        if _pkt and len(_pkt) >= 14:
            if struct.unpack("!H", _pkt[12:14])[0] > 1500:
                return Ether
        return cls
```

A more complex and complete example if you need can be found [in TorPylle](https://github.com/cea-sec/TorPylle/blob/master/torpylle.py#L116), an implementation of the TOR protocol in Scapy.

Comment: Thanks will look into the implementation to understand more!!